# uninitialized constant RSpec with spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spork

I'm trying to get spork working with a rails 2.3.18 app

Here is part of my gemfile showing Rspec versions:

```
gem "rails", "2.3.18"
gem "haml", "3.1.8"
gem "twitter", :git => "git://github.com/sferik/twitter.git", :tag => "v0.9.12"
gem 'rdoc', '~> 3.9.2'

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec", "1.3.1"
  # gem 'rspec-mocks', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rspec-core', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rspec-expectations', '2.1.0'
  gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.4"
  # gem 'guard'
  # gem 'guard-livereload'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  # gem 'em-websocket'
    gem 'spork'
end
```

Here is my spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However,
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.

  # This file is copied to ~/spec when you run 'ruby script/generate rspec'
  # from the project root directory.
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
  require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..','config','environment'))
  require 'spec/autorun'
  require 'spec/rails'

  # Uncomment the next line to use webrat's matchers
  #require 'webrat/integrations/rspec-rails'

  # Requires supporting files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in ./support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'support','**','*.rb'))].each {|f| require f}

  Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord you should remove these
  # lines, delete config/database.yml and disable :active_record
  # in your config/boot.rb
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
  config.fixture_path = RAILS_ROOT + '/spec/fixtures/'

  # == Fixtures
  #
  # You can declare fixtures for each example_group like this:
  #   describe "...." do
  #     fixtures :table_a, :table_b
  #
  # Alternatively, if you prefer to declare them only once, you can
  # do so right here. Just uncomment the next line and replace the fixture
  # names with your fixtures.
  #
  # config.global_fixtures = :table_a, :table_b
  #
  # If you declare global fixtures, be aware that they will be declared
  # for all of your examples, even those that don't use them.
  #
  # You can also declare which fixtures to use (for example fixtures for test/fixtures):
  #
  # config.fixture_path = RAILS_ROOT + '/spec/fixtures/'
  #
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # RSpec uses its own mocking framework by default. If you prefer to
  # use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  #
  # == Notes
  #
  # For more information take a look at Spec::Runner::Configuration and Spec::Runner
end

end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end

# --- Instructions ---
# Sort the contents of this file into a Spork.prefork and a Spork.each_run
# block.
#
# The Spork.prefork block is run only once when the spork server is started.
# You typically want to place most of your (slow) initializer code in here, in
# particular, require'ing any 3rd-party gems that you don't normally modify
# during development.
#
# The Spork.each_run block is run each time you run your specs.  In case you
# need to load files that tend to change during development, require them here.
# With Rails, your application modules are loaded automatically, so sometimes
# this block can remain empty.
#
# Note: You can modify files loaded *from* the Spork.each_run block without
# restarting the spork server.  However, this file itself will not be reloaded,
# so if you change any of the code inside the each_run block, you still need to
# restart the server.  In general, if you have non-trivial code in this file,
# it's advisable to move it into a separate file so you can easily edit it
# without restarting spork.  (For example, with RSpec, you could move
# non-trivial code into a file spec/support/my_helper.rb, making sure that the
# spec/support/* files are require'd from inside the each_run block.)
#
# Any code that is left outside the two blocks will be run during preforking
# *and* during each_run -- that's probably not what you want.
#
# These instructions should self-destruct in 10 seconds.  If they don't, feel
# free to delete them.
```

Spork starts successfully.

When I run

```
./script/spec spec
```

the tests run successfully.  However, if I pass the --drb option like so

```
./script/spec spec --drb
```

I get

```
Exception encountered: #<NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to use `gem 'spork', '~> 0.8.0'`